# ubuntu whois-redirect is not working for jwhois

Tags: ubuntu, whois

I using following query for whois lookup at ubuntu 16.04
`jwhois 99webtools.com`

**Output**

```
 [whois.verisign-grs.com]
   Domain Name: 99WEBTOOLS.COM
   Registry Domain ID: 1836292680_DOMAIN_COM-VRSN
   Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.PublicDomainRegistry.com
   Registrar URL: http://www.publicdomainregistry.com
   Updated Date: 2017-07-27T03:33:56Z
   Creation Date: 2013-11-21T07:14:28Z
   Registry Expiry Date: 2017-11-21T07:14:28Z
   Registrar: PDR Ltd. d/b/a PublicDomainRegistry.com
   Registrar IANA ID: 303
   Registrar Abuse Contact Email: abuse-contact@publicdomainregistry.com
   Registrar Abuse Contact Phone: +1.2013775952
   Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
   Name Server: NS1.HOSTNOLOGY.COM
   Name Server: NS2.HOSTNOLOGY.COM
   DNSSEC: unsigned
   URL of the ICANN Whois Inaccuracy Complaint Form: https://www.icann.org/wicf/
>>> Last update of whois database: 2017-08-23T13:44:46Z <<<

For more information on Whois status codes, please visit https://icann.org/epp
```

jwhois is not querying Registrar WHOIS Server which is **whois.PublicDomainRegistry.com** so whois output is missing other information like contact details.

Answer (score 0):

Things have changed around the time you did your query, about the registry whois output, which broke multiple whois clients and due to the fact that .COM/.NET is still a thin registry at that time. Try again now, and update your whois client you should now see all data.